# join, group and join again in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by, subquery

I have problem making proper query for this kind of need. I hope someone can clear my mind.

Let's say that I have these three tables:

A-TABLE

```
Column1|Column2
```

B-TABLE

```
Column3|Column4
```

C-TABLE

```
Column5|Column6
```

First these tables A and B should be left joined when `A-TABLE.Column1 = B-TABLE.Column3`. This table should be also filtered with WHERE clause because I don't need all the rows.

Then, it's necessary to group by this new joined table so that after that I got table that contains `SUM()` of `B-TABLE.Column3` grouped by `A-TABLE.Column1`.

So, after this I should join the table to C-TABLE so that `C-TABLE.Column5 = A-TABLE.Column1`.

I hope someone can help me achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you post some sample data for each table and then the desired result of the query?  Also it would be helpful if we could see any of the attempts that you have made on the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes by your specs :

```
;With SomeCTE As
(
    Select A-TABLE.Column1
         , Sum(C-TABLE.Column3) As SomeSum
      From C-TABLE
      Left Join A-TABLE On C-TABLE.Column3 = A-TABLE.Column1
     --Where ...
     Group By A-TABLE.Column1
)
Select Column1
     , Column5
     , SomeSum
  From SomeCTE
 Inner Join C-TABLE On SomeCTE.Column1 = C-TABLE.Column5
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dominic. This solution helped me to archive what I was looking for.